# Find out how many thousands and hundreds and tens are there in a amount

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am having a asp application and in that amount column is there. I need to find out how many thousands and hundreds and tens are there in that amount

For example

if i am having amount as 3660 means
1000's - 3
100's - 6
10's - 6

like this i need

Can any body help me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple answer is to divide the number by 1000 whatever is the quotient that is the number of 1000's in the amount. Then divide the remainder with the 100's the quotient will be the number of 100's. And then again divide the remainder with 10, the quotient will be the number of 10's

Something like this:

```
quotient = 3660 / 1000;     //This will give you 3
remainder = 3660 % 1000;    //This will give you 660
```

Then,

```
quotient1 = remainder/ 100;     //This will give you 6
remainder1 = remainder % 100;    //This will give you 60
```

And finally

```
quotient2 = remainder1 / 10;     //This will give you 6
```

Comment: You can implement the above idea in Asp as well as in Javascript! :)

Comment: Thank you i just achieve this result in sql from the above idea

Answer (score 6):

Is it not easier to use type coercion and change the data type to string?

Then you can easily check the value by checking the value at selected index position,

```
var number = 1234;
number2 = new String(number);
var thousands = number2[0];
var hundreds = number2[1];
```

and so on....

It may not be usable in what you're doing, it was for me :)

Comment: Good first answer! maybe you should `parseInt()` the results? to make them available for use in calculations?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>If the "javascript" tag is the correct one, then you've already gotten some answers. If the "asp-classic" tag is actually the correct one, then chances are your scripting language is VBScript, not Javascript.</sup>

Did you just pick multiples of 10 as an example, or is that the actual multiple you're looking for? Because if it's the latter, then all you need to do is split the number into digits — that's what the base 10 number system **means**, after all.

```vbs
Function SplitNum(theNum)
   dim L, i, s, n
   n = CStr(theNum)
   L = Len(n)
   s = ""
   for i = 1 to 3
      if s <> "" then s = "," & s
      if i >= L then
        s = "0" & s
      else
        s = Left(Right(n,i+1),1) & s
      end if
   next
   if L > 4 then s = left(n,L-4) & s
   SplitNum = s
End Function
```

If your actual divisors are something other than multiples of 10, you'll need to do arithmetic. The integer division operator in VBScript is `\`. (Integer division is basically the "opposite" of the modulus function.)

```vbs
Function GetMultiples(theNum)
   dim q, r
   q = theNum \ 1000 & ","
   r = theNum Mod 1000
   q = q & r \ 100 & ","
   r = r Mod 100
   q = q & r \ 10
   GetMultiples = q
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have the number 7354. To find the thousands:

```
variable a = 7354 / 1000
variable b = a % 10
```

The number which is stored in variable b now is the number if the thousands.
To find the hundreds:

```
variable c = 7354 / 100
variable d = a % 10
```

The number which is stored in variable d now is the number if the hundreds.
To find the tens:

```
variable e = 7354 / 10
variable f = a % 10
```

The number which is stored in variable f now is the number if the tens.
To find the ones:

```
7354 % 10
```

This works for every number in the place of 7354, even for bigger numbers than 7354.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates how to use the output..
http://jsfiddle.net/Villarrealized/L3AxZ/1/

```
function getMultiplesOfTen(number){
   number = parseInt(number);
   if(typeof(number)!=="number") return number;
    var result = {};

    (function breakDown(num){
        if(isNaN(num))return num;//if it's invalid return
        if(num<=0)return false;
        num = num.toFixed(0);//get rid of decimals

        var divisor = Math.pow(10,num.length-1),//ex. when num = 300, divisor = 100 
        quotient = Math.floor(num/divisor);

        result[divisor]=quotient;//add it to our object
        breakDown(num % divisor);//break down the remainder
    })(number);
        //return result as an object
        return result;
}
```

This function will return an object with the multiple of ten as the key and the number as the value

ex. `getMultiplesOfTen(150)=={100:1,10:5}`  == 1 multiple of 100 and 5 multiples of 10.

Answer (score 0):

The first digit in the quotient of 1,592÷64
1

is in the  Choose... ones tens hundreds thousands   place.

Answer (score 0):

Decide where the first digit of the quotient should be placed. Do not complete the division.

The first digit of the quotient for 2,370÷24
2,370÷24
 should be in the Choose... ones tens hundreds thousands   place

Answer (score 0):

2021 version here:

Cast your number as a string, spread it and reverse it like so:

```
x = 1234
x = [...x.toString()].reverse() // [4, 3, 2, 1]
thous = x[3] // 1
hunds = x[2] // 2
tens  = x[1] // 3
units = x[0] // 4

y = [...x.toString()].reverse()[3] // 1 because 1000 has 3 zeros
```

I suppose you can use some fancy system of powers of 10 to get those indexes. So let's do exactly that and get @Villarrealized 15 lines of 2013 code condensed into just a few lines of 2021 code:

```
function placeValues(someNumber = 1234) {
  x = [...someNumber.toString()].reverse().reduce((p, c, i) => {
    p[10**i] = c;
    return p;
  }, {});
  return x; // {1000:1, 100:2, 10:3, 1:4}
}
```